# Как узнать velocity CharacterController?

Tags: unity3d

Скажу сразу что знаю про CharacterController.velocity, но оно работает не корректно и реагирует только на перемещение по оси y. Нужно для того чтобы персонаж при врезании в стену не шел в нее, проверка на контакт с другими коллайдерами не подойдет
Как еще можно вычислять velocity CC? Ну или как еще можно реализовать "не ходьбу в стену", не через столкновение? Игра 3d
Сам код перемещения:

```
void Update () {
            moveSpeed = 3f;
            //остальной код
            Vector3 moveVector = (cam.transform.right * joystick.Horizontal + cam.transform.forward * joystick.Vertical);
            moveVector.y = 0.0f;
            moveSpeed *= moveVector.magnitude;
            if (CharacterController.isGrounded) {
                    CharacterController.Move (moveVector * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                    //еще код
            }
            CharacterController.SimpleMove (Physics.gravity * 3 * Time.deltaTime);
            Debug.Log (CharacterController.velocity); //x и z всегда 0
            }
```

Comment: А где проверка на то, что объекты столкнулись?

Comment: @And, ее нет, мне нужно узнать именно относительную скорость перемещения, просто столкновение не подходит

Comment: Кидай физический каст в направлении движения, если расстояние меньше или равно, чем текущий вектор смещения+радиус капсулы, то не двигаться.